# Adobe premiere Pro or After effects: is there a way to to programmatically make cuts?

Tags: adobe, after-effects-scripting, premiere-pro

Wondering if there was a way to make an automated cuts programmatically (e.g.) show time ranges [0-1:00, 2:00-2:15, etc..]

If I have a 1 hour long video and I know by time code for each cut and wanted to automate to trim. is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Both After Effects and Premiere Pro are scriptable using the extendscript API Adobe have provided for them: here are docs for [AE](https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/) and [PP](https://ppro-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/). Extendscript is based on Javascript (ES5).

Whether doing it by scripting or by hand is quicker depends on your coding skills and how fast you can learn the quirks of the API.

There is also a [visual coding environment](https://mamoworld.com/docs/automation-blocks/) for after effects recently released (july 2022) in public beta that might help if you're unfamiliar with JS.